# Google maps v3: Ajax -> Database -> InfoWindow -> Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I almost got it. Almost.

After a couple of days trying to ajax data from database to infowindows.... , now all markers get the right infowindow... except the last entry in the database, which always get undefined.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gloak/NMPRP/10/).

Why do I get undefined in just one entry? It looks like when the program is first loaded, it's empty, but after the first cycle, it is still undefined, for ever and ever...

Here is the code, which is slightly different from fiddle because of Ajax.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. I have been doing computer for a few months and just to get this infowindow (almost) right, took me quite a few readings on ajax, closure and such. I have a vague idea why I had to create that parameter/variable "box" in the function dropmarker (...box), but it works, I mean, it almost works. If I don't use the `box.name`, but the `pos.lat ()`, then all is good. But I need the other values, because the final project will be a link to Youtube. I need to be able to bring all values.

```
var BERLIN = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.517683, -46.394393);
var map = null;
var marker = null;
var index = 0;
var infoWindow = [];
var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';



function initialize() {

         var featureOpts = [ ]  // lots personal options deleted to shorten code
         var mapOptions = {} // lots personal options deleted to shorten code
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);


         var styledMapOptions = { name: 'Custom Style'
         };

        var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

        map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
        function dropMarker (map,box, pos ){                                          return new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: pos,
                                draggable: false,
                                }); // return

            //end of function
        }


        function changeMarker() {   

            if (marker) {
                infoWindow.close();
                marker.setMap(null);

            }

            var pos = neighborhood[index];
            var box = infowindows[index];
            marker = dropMarker(map,box, pos );
            var contentString = ('lat:' + box.lat+ '<br />' + 'lng:' + box.lng  + '<br />' + 'link:' +  box.link + '<br />' +'name:' + box.name)
            infoWindow.setContent( contentString);


            setTimeout(function () {
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }, 200);

            index = (index + 1) % neighborhood.length;

            setTimeout(function () {
                changeMarker();
            }, 3000);
    } 

            customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions); // this seems to be optional
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ()  

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'php/locationsJson.php',
                    dataType : 'json',

                    success: function( json ){
                            neighborhood=[];
                            infowindows =[];
                            $.each(json,function(i,item){
                                neighborhood.push(new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat,this.lng));
                                infowindows.push(infoWindow)
                                contentString = ({link:this.link,name:this.name,lat:this.lat,lng:this.lng})
                                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow (contentString)     
                                alert ( infowindows)                    
                         });    //$.each

             changeMarker();    
                    } // end of success
                });//end of ajax        
}  //end of initialized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push `infoWindow` after you have set its value. Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMPRP/11/)

```
contentString = ({

    lat: this.lat,
    lng: this.lng,
    name: this.name,
});
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(contentString)
});
infowindows.push(infoWindow);
```